# Queries that rank users according to the number of close/reopen votes they have cast

Tags: support, vote-to-close, votes, data-explorer

I know that I can check this statistics for my profile by going to the "votes" tab. But for other users I can not do the same (it is hidden).

I want to see which users have cast the most number of close or reopen votes.

So, is it possible to create such queries?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I have written here is to the best of my knowledge, but I am only a beginner at using the [SE data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) and corrections may be due. I did not write the queries mentioned but only slightly adjusted them. Others will certainly be able to improve them.

To some extent, votes are private. The public database mainly includes information that is somehow publicly accessible and excludes information that could compromise privacy. Close voters are listed under a closed post and permanently in the timeline. Reopen voters can also be seen in the timeline. Timeline information is in the data explorer, so it is possible to get a limited version of the information you want.

#### Close Voters

[This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/hinduism/revision/956541/1186000/top-close-voters) should return the top close voters.

Note that:

- It uses the PostHistory table record for close stats. The relevant schema stores the fact that the post was closed. Unsuccessful close votes are not accessible as far as I know, so this is only a count of those votes that resulted in the post being closed.
- Deleted posts are not included. This is a problem, because closing questions makes it much more likely that they will be deleted. But I do not think the PostsWithDeleted table has enough data to fix this because it has no user data.

#### Reopen Voters

[This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/hinduism/revision/956565/1186004/top-reopen-voters) should return the top reopen voters.

Note that:

- It uses the PostHistory table record for reopen stats. The relevant schema stores the fact that the post was reopened. Unsuccessful reopen votes are not accessible as far as I know, so this is only a count of those votes that resulted in the post being reopened.
- Deleted posts are not included.

Comment: I was also trying to modify [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/opendata/query/866211/top-close-voters) but you posted first. I think its not working properly because I have also successfully re-opened some posts but its not showing. One example is [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/31535/revisions).

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani I am very willing to believe it is not working properly, but the post you linked to was reopened very recently and the data only gets dumped once a week, sometimes less often, so may not include that one yet. According to my version you have participated in 52 successful votes to reopen...

Comment: That was only one example. There are many posts to which I have voted to re-open and they have re-opened. Now, your changed query is showing correct info.

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani oh! I am surprised that the small change I made fixed that. There may still be problems with it. Thanks a lot for reporting the inconsistency! Please feel free to post a better answer if you manage to improve the query more...